# SSD gone bad suddenly

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, crash, sata

**Problem:**

A few days ago I had a crash in Windows 8. It was just freezing content by a little bit until the only thing that could move was the mouse pointer. I instantly got an idea it was something wrong with my system drive because it still did show contents loaded into memory. I rebooted the machine and suddenly got a BSOD (or a similar thing) stating that *I have to repair my pc*.

After numerous restarts it did not come back, but after complete power cycle it did. But not for long, just until I fired up my browser and opened some websites - and it crashed the same way again.

I have a dual boot Windows Server (for education purposes) which is on another drive. Tried booting into that - everything's okay. But until I tried to write or copy something to the drive. It instantly become laggy, the My Computer is very slow and after a while it loaded, but the drive icon no longer showed the capacity bar and you could not open the drive.

Then, after a reboot, I tried some programs that show SMART information for a drive - all the parameters are excellent.

I tried connecting to different SATA port on the motherboard, replacing SATA cable, plugging another power connector. The voltages on the PSU are fine. I even tried a different PC. So the problem is in the drive.

**Questions:**

What can be wrong with it? What is the best way to restore my personal data from the drive or even make a whole image of the drive in this situation? I don't want to try anything stupid as it can stop working at all and I'll lose my data.

**Hardware:**

Motherboard: ASUS P8Z77

SSD: [120 GB Kingston HyperX](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/sh103s3_us.pdf)

Comment: "*got a BSOD (or a similar thing) stating that I have to repair my pc*" That's a very imprecise description. What was the exact message? And was it a BSOD or wasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

SSDs only have a limited lifetime, but since the SMART parameters are fine, try the following steps: Boot into a Linux live CD to see if it works to exclude a software issue like a corrupted driver. Next, run a memory testing program at boot time, since the issues you described can be caused by faulty RAM. Lastly, if you can do it at all, format the ssd and try using it with a fresh install on a different PC for a while and see if it shows any symptoms. About backing up your data: Try DriveImage XML or simply cp under Linux. If that doesn't work, it is likely that only a format might help, or the SSD has reached its end of life.

Read this to learn more about SSD wear: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#Wear_leveling